# Is there one to one relationship between java package and directory?

Tags: java, package, directory, netbeans-7

Learning java newly. Can anybody clear my doubt in following?

My demo application has code like this

> SourcePackages ---> ex1.pkg1
>                  |
>                   --->food
>
> 1. My ex1.pkg1 has one class called Ex11 and it contains the main function.
> 2. My food package contains one abstract class fruit and another subclass of class fruit as Apple.
> 3. I am creating an instance of Apple class in my main function in class Ex11.

The code compiles fine and runs also fine. But I am trying to understand the directory structure in java.

When I run the program I can see the following folders inside the build/class directory

> 1. ex1 -> pkg1 -> Ex11.class
> 2. food -> Apple.class and fruit.class
> 3. fruit -> empty

I don't understood why the directory fruit is created although I don't have any package named fruit? Even if I delete it and compile again its not created. But created when I run the application.

Extra Info - I am using netbean IDE

Comment: Do you have any inner class !

Comment: search in your code if you have defined package as ex1.pkg1.fruit of any of these classes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question Not exactly. You can create same directory structures ( hence same package) in different locations and even in different jars. For example; you can have  directories CoreDomain\com\example and CoreServices\com\example. Now, classes within these two directories will have same package com.example even though they are in different directories ( but same directory with ref. to starting point ; as both are in com.example )